# CSS vertical text orientation not working on iOS Safari for dynamic buttons

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a vertical layout for buttons that will be displayed on the right side of the page. Each button should have its text rotated vertically along the Y-axis. I have tried using the writing-mode: vertical-rl; property, but it's not working on iOS Safari.

**Below is the image of my expected result**

[image]

**This is how it is coming currently on real iphone/mobile device**

[image]

Here's the HTML code for the buttons:

```css
#business-id {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Stack items vertically */
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  padding-right: 5px;
  top: 50% !important;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#business-id a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Stack icon and button vertically */
  align-items: center;
}

#business-id .icon {
  margin-bottom: 8px; /* Add spacing between icon and button */
}

#business-id button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* Rotate the button text vertically */
}
```

```html
<div id="business-id" class="vertical">
  <!-- Buttons will be dynamically generated -->
  <!-- Each button will have a span with class "icon" for an icon image -->
  <!-- Each button will have a class "integrated-btn btn btn-appointment" -->
  <a>
    <span class="icon"><img src="https://g99plus.b-cdn.net/singlescript/img3.svg"></span>
    <button class="integrated-btn btn btn-appointment">Button 1</button>
  </a>

  <a>
    <span class="icon"><img src="https://g99plus.b-cdn.net/singlescript/img3.svg"></span>
    <button class="integrated-btn btn btn-appointment">Button 2</button>
  </a>
  
  <!-- More buttons will be added dynamically -->
</div>
```

I need a CSS solution that will work on iOS Safari to rotate the button text vertically along the Y-axis. Additionally, since the number of buttons is dynamic and will be added programmatically, I cannot give specific CSS rules to each button individually.

Below is the live website on which I am facing the issue for the mobile devices.
https://drbrianharris.com/

Comment: The issue seems to be with the button element. A div is OK.

Comment: Just as a comment, put your code through a validator. The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any sources to prove my answer, but i guess writing-mode doesn't affect buttons, or there is some trick to getting it to work. As a solution, you could probably wrap the buttons in a div and using writing-mode, or maybe you could use transform to rotate the buttons.

In my example I wrap the button text in a span and add the writing-mode to the span and not the button and then rotate the text.

```css
#business-id {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Stack items vertically */
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  padding-right: 5px;
  top: 50% !important;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#business-id a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Stack icon and button vertically */
  align-items: center;
}

#business-id .icon {
  margin-bottom: 8px; /* Add spacing between icon and button */
}

#business-id button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#business-id .text {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* Rotate the button text vertically */
  transform: rotate(180deg); // for correct orientation

}
```

```html
<div id="business-id" class="vertical">
  <!-- Buttons will be dynamically generated -->
  <!-- Each button will have a span with class "icon" for an icon image -->
  <!-- Each button will have a class "integrated-btn btn btn-appointment" -->
  <a>
    <span class="icon"><img src="https://g99plus.b-cdn.net/singlescript/img3.svg"></span>
    <button class="integrated-btn btn btn-appointment"><span class="text">Button 1</span></button>
  </a>

  <a>
    <span class="icon"><img src="https://g99plus.b-cdn.net/singlescript/img3.svg"></span>
    <button class="integrated-btn btn btn-appointment">Button 2</button>
  </a>
  
  <!-- More buttons will be added dynamically -->
</div>
```

Comment: "i guess writing-mode doesn't affect buttons" Are you referring to Safari on iOS? Does your example work as intended in Safari on iOS? Also, you omitted `</span>`