# Rotated text works on Desktop, but is upside down on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, google-chrome, rotation, transform

I am using the following CSS to achieve the rotated header that I want on desktop browsers (Edge and Chrome):

[image]

To do that I'm using the following style:

```
.table-rotated-header {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  top: 100%;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: start;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

The issue is that when I view that on Safari or Chrome on the iPhone The header is upside down.  I've tried using -webkit-transform values but those don't seem to have any effect.

I've tried using -webkit-transform: rotate with different values but even with cache clearing on the iPhone it doesn't change the text orientation.

How can I achieve the rotated header like in the image on both desktop and iPhone browsers?

Comment: I found this reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742197/css-vertical-text-orientation-not-working-on-ios-safari-for-dynamic-buttons and it suggested that <button> didn't work on IOS.  I tried wrapping a div inside my table header and that seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the contents of the table header inside of a div and applying the CSS class to the div solved the problem.  I did not need to use -webkit-transform, but I did have to change the rotate to -90deg and it looked right on both IOS and desktop.